# How to add logo to a website which has CSS/HTML/JS and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, header

I am a newbie to Front-end development and learning it through watching Videos, Reading the available material on Internet.I am currently using HTML, CSS, JS for my website. Can anyone please assist me how should I add Logo to the Website as whenever I add image to the header it is occupying the while page.

```
Below is the HTML & CSS


<div class="container">
<div class="nav-header">
<a href="#" class="js-fh5co-nav-toggle fh5co-nav-toggle dark"><i></i></a>
<h1 id="fh5co-logo"><a href="index.html"><i class="icon-airplane"></i>Wayfarer Tours</a></h1>
<!-- START #fh5co-menu-wrap -->
<nav id="fh5co-menu-wrap" role="navigation">

.nav-header {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

#fh5co-logo {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 35px;
  font-weight: 700;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
#fh5co-logo i {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #F78536;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  padding: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
#fh5co-logo a {
  color: #F78536;
}
#fh5co-logo a:hover, #fh5co-logo a:focus {
  color: #F78536 !important;
}

#fh5co-menu-wrap {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;``
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
#fh5co-menu-wrap .sf-menu a {
  padding: 1em .75em;
}

#fh5co-primary-menu > li > ul li.active > a {
  color: #F78536 !important;
}
#fh5co-primary-menu > li > .sf-with-ul:after {
  border: none !important;
  font-family: 'icomoon';
  speak: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-transform: none;
  line-height: 1;
  /* Better Font Rendering =========== */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  margin-right: -0px;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: -7px;
  content: "\e922";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the width to the logo container. Also add the max-width to the image so that it will adjust in the container according to screen size.

```
#fh5co-logo
{
   width:30%;
}
#fh5co-logo img
{
   max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But still the problem persist..I will try to read and find out more.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width and height to the "fh5co-logo" element.